# Visual page editor of jboss-tools does not recognize "Named" annotation

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2, jboss-tools

We are using the visual page editor of the jboss-tools in our Eclipse (actually a Spring tool suite) for editing JSF2 files. We were suprised to learn that the editor would only recognize the backing beans that are annotated with the (deprecated) annotation `ManagedBean`, as we use only Spring-managed beans. We tried and use the JSR-330 annotation `Named`, but this is not recognized either. Is there a specific reason for this behaviour? Can we somehow enable jboss-tools to recognize the `Named` beans? We don't want to add `ManagedBean` just for the editor.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Works fine for me with plain eclipse and jboss tools (no spring stuff)

Comment: Thank you for your input. I can actually confirm this. I will investigate this further.